# paste special in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, paste, vba

I wrote macro (on personal.xlsb, because I want to use it in every Excel sheet) and assign to it shortcut.
Unfortunately I get an error message - what's wrong
(object variable not set error 91):

```
Public Sub wklej_specjalnie() 

    'wklej_specjalnie Makro ' 
    'Klawisz skrótu: Ctrl+Shift+v '

    On Error Resume Next

    ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the exact purpose of this macro?  I'm guessing that the values that are being pasted to the active cell are from the Clipboard, no?  Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to specify `ActiveSheet`; `ActiveCell` is the active cell on the active sheet. This should work for you:

```
Public Sub wklej_specjalnie() 

    'wklej_specjalnie Makro ' 
    'Klawisz skrótu: Ctrl+Shift+v '

    On Error Resume Next

    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 

End Sub
```